# Drawing non-static rectangle programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to draw a **non-static** (variable width height x y) **filled rectangle** in WPF. I have experience with Winforms but I never used WPF before. This is what I would do in WinForm using GDI+ drawing calls.

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(_brush1, _rect1);
}
```

And also, I would call `this.Invalidate()` whenever I change my `_rect1` properties.

All the "tutorials" I have seen on this matter are only drawing static non-filled rectangles inside `.xaml` files (or they don't mention where the code the show goes...).

I know WPF's painting works differently, I just don't understand how. I found a [similar method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.onrender(v=vs.110).aspx) `protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)` and trying adding this on the default class I got when I made my project `public partial class MainWindow : Window`, but nothing is drawn on the screen. Another thing that concerns me, is that `DrawingContext` class has only a `DrawRectangle` class and there is no  `FillRectangle`.

How can I draw something like this efficiently ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to override `OnRender` in WPF. Technically, you can, of course, but it brings a lot of problems and it's generally not recommended.

What I would do is have a panel on the window, ideally a `Canvas`, then create a `Rectangle` object which you can then manipulate from the code-behind (or, better yet, using data binding). If you put it in the `Canvas`, you can manipulate its size and position by changing its `Width` and `Height` and the attached properties `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top`.

Without knowing your specific scenario it is difficult to offer more specific advice.

Edit: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559708/drawing-and-removing-shapes-in-wpf?rq=1) related question has some good answers and examples.

Comment: how will i access my canvas with code ? and how will the rectangle be filled ?

Comment: `Rectangle` has properties like `Fill` and `Stroke` that define the colors. The linked question has good examples, though if you're a beginner in WPF, a lot of stuff in there will probably confuse you. Unfortunately what you're trying to do isn't the easiest thing to do in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the way you should use WPF. It has another philosophy of creating graphics. But if you are looking for a method which is analogous to the the Windows Forms way you could use this:

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
    base.OnRender(drawingContext);

    Background = Brushes.Transparent;
    drawingContext.DrawRectangle(
       Brushes.BlueViolet, new Pen(Brushes.Chartreuse, 2), new Rect(10, 10, 1000, 1000));
}
```

As you see you have to set the background transparent.

Comment: I mention in my question that I want to do the drawing efficiently

Comment: It is efficient as it is low level and so it is fast. If you are looking for a way which is efficient for the programmer you have to read about the basics of WPF: XAML, Shapes, Drawings, DrawingContext. It is very powerful but it needs some time to understand it in the beginning.