# How to drag move, resize/scale, rotate a control element on a Canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, contentcontrol

I'm trying to create Diagram Designer with WPF and using the MVVM pattern, I take information and some tips from this guide: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-1

And in one moment, my project looks like:

[WPF: Hydrate Canvas with Draggable Controls at Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952836/wpf-hydrate-canvas-with-draggable-controls-at-runtime)

And of course I had the similar problem as the author mentioned above: when I draw my `ContentControl`, it's drawing correctly with random coordinates, but when I try to move it, it won't move! And when I debug the class `MoveThumb`, I see that my `ContentControl` has not got its `Parent`. But in my opinion, it should have `Canvas` as a `Parent`. I understand that I should override some system/basic method, but I can't understand what and how should I override it. Maybe someone has an idea?

Now I try to describe my implementation, first i create BaseShapeViewModel

```
abstract public class BaseShapeViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

    public BaseShapeViewModel()
    {

    }

    private double left;
    public double Left
    {
        get => left;
        set => SetField(ref left, value, nameof(Left));
    }

    private double top;
    public double Top
    {
        get => top;
        set => SetField(ref top, value, nameof(Top));
    }

    private int width;
    public int Width
    {
        get => width;
        set => SetField(ref width, value, nameof(Width));
    }

    private int height;
    public int Height
    {
        get => height;
        set => SetField(ref height, value, nameof(Height));
    }

    private string fill;
    public string Fill
    {
        get => fill;
        set => SetField(ref fill, value, nameof(Fill));
    }

    private string text;
    public string Text
    {
        get => text;
        set => SetField(ref text, value, nameof(Text));
    }

}
```

other ViewModels EllipseViewModel, RectangleViewModel inherit from BaseShapeViewModel.
My MainViewModel looks like

```
class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {          
        BaseShapeViewModels = new ObservableCollection<BaseShapeViewModel>();                    
    }

    public ObservableCollection<BaseShapeViewModel> BaseShapeViewModels { get; set; }

    //public Canvas DesignerCanvas;
   
    private RelayCommand createUseCase;
    private RelayCommand createRectangle;

    public ICommand CreateUseCase
    {
        get
        {
            return createUseCase ?? 
                (
                    createUseCase = new RelayCommand(() => { AddUseCase(); })                    
                );
        }
    }
    public ICommand CreateRectangle
    {
        get
        {
            return createRectangle ??
                (
                    createRectangle = new RelayCommand(() => { AddRectangle(); })
                );
        }
    }

    private void AddUseCase()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        
        int valueLeft = rnd.Next(0, 200);
        int valueTop = rnd.Next(0, 200);
        
        EllipseViewModel useCaseViewModel = new EllipseViewModel {Left=valueLeft,Top=valueTop, Height = 100, Width = 200, Fill="Blue"};
        BaseShapeViewModels.Add(useCaseViewModel);
  
    }

    private void AddRectangle()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        
        int valueLeft = rnd.Next(0, 200);
        int valueTop = rnd.Next(0, 200);

        RectangleViewModel rectangleViewModel = new RectangleViewModel { Left = valueLeft, Top = valueTop, Height = 100, Width = 200, Fill = "Blue" };
        BaseShapeViewModels.Add(rectangleViewModel);
    }
}
```

My MoveThumb.cs looks like

```
 public class MoveThumb : Thumb
{
  
    public MoveThumb()
    {
        DragDelta += new DragDeltaEventHandler(this.MoveThumb_DragDelta);
    }

    private void MoveThumb_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        ContentControl designerItem = DataContext as ContentControl;
       
        if (designerItem != null)
        {
            Point dragDelta = new Point(e.HorizontalChange, e.VerticalChange);
            
            RotateTransform rotateTransform = designerItem.RenderTransform as RotateTransform;
            if (rotateTransform != null)
            {
                dragDelta = rotateTransform.Transform(dragDelta);
            }
            double left = Canvas.GetLeft(designerItem);
            double top = Canvas.GetTop(designerItem);
           
            Canvas.SetLeft(designerItem, left + dragDelta.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(designerItem, top + dragDelta.Y);       
        }

    }
}
```

And know i want to say that im not profi at Xaml, but i check material from the first link and create MoveThumb.xaml like this

```
<ResourceDictionary 

<ControlTemplate x:Key="MoveThumbTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type s:MoveThumb}">
    <Rectangle Fill="Transparent"/>
</ControlTemplate>
```

after i create ResizeDecorator and RotateDecorator, but right now it doesnt matter, and create DesignerItem.xaml

```
ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="MoveThumb.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="ResizeDecorator.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="RotateDecorator.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<!-- ContentControl style to move, resize and rotate items -->
<Style x:Key="DesignerItemStyle" TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="50"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="50"/>
    <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                    <Control Name="RotateDecorator"
                             Template="{StaticResource RotateDecoratorTemplate}"
                             Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    <s:MoveThumb Template="{StaticResource MoveThumbTemplate}"
                                 Cursor="SizeAll"/>
                    <Control x:Name="ResizeDecorator"
                             Template="{StaticResource ResizeDecoratorTemplate}"
                             Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="ResizeDecorator" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="RotateDecorator" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And i try to Bind this Style in my MainWindow.xaml for my ContentControls

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/DesignerItem.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Background="Gray" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <TextBlock Text="Shapes"                      
                   FontSize="18"
                   TextAlignment="Center" />
        <Button Content="Initial Node" />
        <Button Content="Final Node" />
        <Button Content="Line" />
        <Button Content="Action" />
        <Button Content="Decision Node" />
        <Button Content="Actor" />
        <Button Content="Class" Command="{Binding Path=CreateRectangle}"/>
        <Button Content="Use Case" Command="{Binding Path = CreateUseCase}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <Grid Grid.Column="2">

        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path= BaseShapeViewModels}">

            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>

                    <Canvas/>

                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

            <ItemsControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:EllipseViewModel}">
                    <ContentControl
                                           Selector.IsSelected="True"
                                           Style="{StaticResource DesignerItemStyle}">

                        <Ellipse 
                                           Fill="{Binding Fill}"                                               
                                           IsHitTestVisible="False"/>

                    </ContentControl>
                </DataTemplate>

                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:RectangleViewModel}">
                    <ContentControl             
                                           Selector.IsSelected="True"
                                           Style="{StaticResource DesignerItemStyle}">

                        <Rectangle 
                                           Fill="{Binding Fill}"                                              
                                           IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                    </ContentControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Resources>

            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Width, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Height,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ItemsControl>
        
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to move objects on a `Canvas` programmatically or by drag?

Comment: @BionicCode , better maybe programmaticlly, but without a lot of MouseEvents like MouseLeftButtomUp, Down , i love how Sucram from the first link create movement, its has logic, and i actually understand what he do,  because its sometimes hard for me and i want stick his style

Comment: Could you provide some details about your implementation?

Comment: @BionicCode i edit my question, know you can check my implementation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't drag the items across the `Canvas`, because you are using an `ItemsControl`. This control wraps each item into a container. You are currently trying to drag the content of this container, but not the container. It is the container that is actually positioned within the `Canvas`.

To reduce complexity I recommend to implement a custom control that extends `ItemsControl`. This way you can make the item container itself draggable. Alternatively you can implement an attached behavior.

To provide a resize and rotate user interface (e.g. resize grip), I recommend to use the `Adorner`.

The following example implements a custom item container, which supports drag, scale and rotation, and an extended `ItemsControl` that uses this container for its items.
Since the draggable element is a `ContentControl`, it doesn't need any additional wrapping. This will simplify the usage as shown below.

### Implementing `DraggableContentControl`

**DraggableContentControl.cs**
The `DraggableContentControl` class is used as the item container of the `ItemsCanvas` control (the specialized `ItemsControl` - see below).

In addition, the `DraggableContentControl` can be used as stand-alone control: the `DraggableContentControl` is a very convenient and reusable way to add mouse drag, scale and rotation to any `UIElement` on a `Canvas`.   For example to allow to drag a `Rectangle` across the `Canvas` simply assign the `Rectangle` to the `DraggableContentControl.Content` property and position the `DraggableContentControl` on a `Canvas`:

```
<Canvas Width="1000" Height="1000">

 <!-- Ad mouse drag, rotation and scaling to a Rectangle -->
  <DraggableContentControl Canvas.Left="50" 
                           Canvas.Top="50" 
                           Angle="45">
        <Rectangle Height="100" 
                   Width="100" 
                   Fill="Coral" />
  </DraggableContentControl>
</Canvas>
```

**Rotation** : setting the `DraggableContentControl.Angle` allows to rotate the hosted element.
**Scaling**: setting `DraggableContentControl.Width` and `DraggableContentControl.Height` allows to scale/resize the content (automatically, because the `DraggableContentControl.Content` value is wrapped into a `Viewbox` - see the default `Style` below).
By default, when the size is set to `Auto`, the `DraggableContentControl` will dynamically adopt the size of its content.

```
public class DraggableContentControl : ContentControl
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty AngleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Angle",
    typeof(double),
    typeof(DraggableContentControl),
    new PropertyMetadata(default(double), DraggableContentControl.OnAngleChanged));

  public double Angle
  {
    get => (double) GetValue(DraggableContentControl.AngleProperty);
    set => SetValue(DraggableContentControl.AngleProperty, value);
  }

  private RotateTransform RotateTransform { get; set; }
  private IInputElement ParentInputElement { get; set; }
  private bool IsDragActive { get; set; }
  private Point DragOffset { get; set; }

  static DraggableContentControl()
  {
    // Remove this line if you don't plan to define the default Style
    // inside the Generic.xaml file.
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DraggableContentControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(DraggableContentControl)));
  }

  public DraggableContentControl()
  {
    this.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += InitializeDrag_OnLeftMouseButtonDown;
    this.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += CompleteDrag_OnLeftMouseButtonUp;
    this.PreviewMouseMove += Drag_OnMouseMove;
    this.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);

    var transformGroup = new TransformGroup();
    this.RotateTransform = new RotateTransform();
    transformGroup.Children.Add(this.RotateTransform);
    this.RenderTransform = transformGroup;
  }

  #region Overrides of FrameworkElement

  public override void OnApplyTemplate()
  {
    base.OnApplyTemplate();

    // Parent is required to calculate the relative mouse coordinates.
    DependencyObject parentControl = this.Parent;
    if (parentControl == null
        && !TryFindParentElement(this, out parentControl)
        && !(parentControl is IInputElement))
    {
      return;
    }

    this.ParentInputElement = parentControl as IInputElement;
  }

  #endregion

  private void InitializeDrag_OnLeftMouseButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
    // Do nothing if disabled
    this.IsDragActive = this.IsEnabled;
    if (!this.IsDragActive)
    {
      return;
    }

    Point relativeDragStartPosition = e.GetPosition(this.ParentInputElement);

    // Calculate the drag offset to allow the content to be dragged 
    // relative to the clicked coordinates (instead of the top-left corner)
    this.DragOffset = new Point(
      relativeDragStartPosition.X - Canvas.GetLeft(this),
      relativeDragStartPosition.Y - Canvas.GetTop(this));

    // Prevent other controls from stealing mouse input while dragging
    CaptureMouse();
  }

  private void CompleteDrag_OnLeftMouseButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
    this.IsDragActive = false;
    ReleaseMouseCapture();
  }

  private void Drag_OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
    if (!this.IsDragActive)
    {
      return;
    }

    Point currentPosition = e.GetPosition(this.ParentInputElement);

    // Apply the drag offset to drag relative to the 
    // initial mouse down coordinates (instead of the top-left corner)
    currentPosition.Offset(-this.DragOffset.X, -this.DragOffset.Y);
    Canvas.SetLeft(this, currentPosition.X);
    Canvas.SetTop(this, currentPosition.Y);
  }

  private static void OnAngleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    (d as DraggableContentControl).RotateTransform.Angle = (double) e.NewValue;
  }

  private bool TryFindParentElement<TParent>(DependencyObject child, out TParent resultElement)
    where TParent : DependencyObject
  {
    resultElement = null;

    if (child == null)
    {
      return false;
    }

    DependencyObject parentElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);

    if (parentElement is TParent)
    {
      resultElement = parentElement as TParent;
      return true;
    }

    return TryFindParentElement(parentElement, out resultElement);
  }
}
```

### Implementing `ItemsCanvas`

**ItemsCanvas.cs**
`ItemsCanvas` is a `ItemsControl` configured to use `DraggableContentControl` as the item container.

```
class ItemsCanvas : ItemsControl
{
  static ItemsCanvas()
  {
    // Remove this line if you don't plan to define the default Style
    // inside the Generic.xaml file.
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ItemsCanvas), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ItemsCanvas)));
  }

  #region Overrides of ItemsControl

  protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item) => item is DraggableContentControl;

  protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride() => new DraggableContentControl();

  #endregion
}
```

**Generic.xaml**

The default styles for the `DraggableContentControl` and the `ItemsCanvas`:

```
<Style TargetType="DraggableContentControl">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="DraggableContentControl">
        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

          <!-- 
            Optional: wrapping the content into a Viewbox
            allows to automatically resize/scale the content 
            based on the container's (DraggableContentControl) size.
          -->
          <Viewbox Stretch="Fill">
            <ContentPresenter />
          </Viewbox>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>


<Style TargetType="ItemsCanvas">
  <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <Canvas />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsCanvas">
        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
          <ScrollViewer>
            <ItemsPresenter />
          </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

---

**Example**
This example is based on your data models.

```
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type RectangleViewModel}">
      <Rectangle Height="{Binding Height}" 
                 Width="{Binding Width}"
                 Fill="{Binding Fill}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type EllipseViewModel}">
      <Ellipse Height="{Binding Height}" 
               Width="{Binding Width}"
               Fill="{Binding Fill}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>

  <ItemsCanvas ItemsSource="{Binding BaseShapeViewModels}" 
               Height="500" 
               Width="500">
    <ItemsCanvas.ItemContainerStyle>

      <!-- Optional Style that adds the possibility to position items on the Canvas 
           using the e.g., Top and Left properties of the data model. 
      -->
      <Style TargetType="main:DraggableContentControl">
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Left, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Top, Mode=TwoWay}" />
      </Style>
    </ItemsCanvas.ItemContainerStyle>
  </ItemsCanvas>
</Window>
```

Comment: I think that your solution is what i really need, i try it right now, but i have problems with displayng my  DraggableContentControls they are created but not displayng, maybe I did something wrong in MainWindow, or at Generic.xaml
Update: I, i fix my problem, thx u a lot!

Comment: Let me know if you encounter any problems.

Answer (score 0):

BionocCode solution work right but i found another way, i change only two methods

```
private void MoveThumb_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        ContentControl designerItem = DataContext as ContentControl;
       

        if (designerItem != null)
        {
            Point dragDelta = new Point(e.HorizontalChange, e.VerticalChange);
            
            RotateTransform rotateTransform = designerItem.RenderTransform as RotateTransform;
            if (rotateTransform != null)
            {
                dragDelta = rotateTransform.Transform(dragDelta);
            }

            /*use this*/
            var model = designerItem.DataContext as BaseShapeViewModel;
            model.Left += dragDelta.X;
            model.Top += dragDelta.Y;

            /* instead of this*/
            //double left = Canvas.GetLeft(item);
            //double top = Canvas.GetTop(item);
            //Canvas.SetLeft(item, left + e.HorizontalChange);
            //Canvas.SetTop(item, top + e.VerticalChange);
        }

    }
```

Look at last 3 lines, i was able to take my ViewModel from my ContentControl and change their properties, when I change them, the properties of the ViewModel object in the ObservableCollection also change and everything is rendered well

Comment: Note that this adds a strong dependency to `BaseShapeViewModel` and its implementation details, removing all the flexibility or reusability. If you would use data binding like your first attempt, then this control can be used with every data model.