# Is it possible to bind to Canvas.Children?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, graphics, canvas

I don't know if this is the best way, but what I am trying to do is to create a collection of `Shape` objects and then bind it to a `Canvas`, then whenever I update these `Shapes`, or add new `Shapes` (rare), the `Shape` objects on the `Canvas` will update as well.

Btw the `Shape` objects are not all the same, some `Lines`, `Rectangles`, etc. Not sure if that matters.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889825/wpf-is-it-possible-to-bind-a-canvass-children-property-in-xaml

Comment: Thanks I saw that one but it seems like it only handles shapes of one type? Also he didn't provide the source for the converter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the question [Is it possible to bind a Canvas's Children property in XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889825/wpf-is-it-possible-to-bind-a-canvass-children-property-in-xaml) and further down there is an answer from Ivan which uses an attached property you can bind to and it automatically updates the canvas children. I haven't tried it but looks like it should work. Seems the best solution to me. The other option is to use the `ItemsControl` with a `DataTemplate` for each type you want to show - however that seems a bit fiddly.

Comment: Thanks I will try that and let you know if it works. Currently I use Path.