# WPF binding to item control

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

i'm new to wpf , i need to place a tow different drawing inside an item-controls items 
according to a specific binding value ,

the item control is for this case a button with a canvas in its content 
i need to render the drawing onto the canvas after performing a check on the bounded value

the item control is bounded to an ObservableCollection of Employee's

The Data Template is as follows (just the relative properties)

```
   <Button>
        <Grid>
            <ViewBox>
                  <Canvas>
                        <!-- Here go some shapes that -->
                  </Canvas>
              </ViewBox>         
        </Grid>
   </Button>
```

my question is , how to go about rendering the shapes through the Binding source 
i thought about a converter which would manually add the shapes from code behind but i cant 
figure out which of the canvas's properties to Bind .

any idea's would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You ca use the [Canvas.Children](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.children.aspx) property. You can place each single element by calling `Canvas.SetTop()`, `Canvas.SetLeft()` on each shape. I agree that some custom converter can do the job you want.

Comment: this is a good approach but i still fail to see how i can bind to the children property

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889825/wpf-is-it-possible-to-bind-a-canvass-children-property-in-xaml

Comment: try with an attached property and bind that property

Comment: sorry , i'm new to wpf 
you mean i need to do something along the lines of  this :
<Canvas Children="{Binding ,Path={StaticResource Collection} }">
well the first problem would be that there doesn't seem to be an attached property of children only <Canvas.Children> which i can't 
Bind any thing to (or don't know how)

Comment: @eran you could not bind the children, but you can create your own attached property and drive the children colection from there.