# Binding collection of objects to Canvas in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, mvvm

I kind of want to make a game.... so I want able to dynamically to add a data object to the Canvas and is dispaly it.

i.e) 
1) a Car object, contains the car information, when it binds to the Canvas, I want to display it as a UserControl (contains some graphic).

2) When the car object display display/add/remove to the Canvas, it should do some animation.

So there is 3 questions:

1. Is it possible to binds to Canvas directly to do things I describe
   above?
2. Is it better I just do it in programmatic way in the code-behind?
3. How do such thing in MVVM? If my Car collection objects is in my ViewModel, the only way I can do is binds that to the View?  Then if I want to let the car do some animation when user press some key, how can I interact with the View using my ViewModel?

Some suggestion will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display animations when the items are added to a panel you can use Fluid Layout from the [Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10801). ([Some demonstration video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/SilverlightTV/Creating-Rich-Interactions-Using-Blend-4-Transition-Effects-Fluid-Layout-and-Layout-States-Silverlig); sadly doesn't show the generated code for those without Blend)

For methods to bind to a canvas see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889825/wpf-is-it-possible-to-bind-a-canvass-children-property-in-xaml).

I would not recommend doing this imperatively.

Comment: Imperatively? So I should stay using MVVM for this?  Is there any reason?

Comment: @KingChan: It's not about MVVM, it's about imperative vs. declarative. Data binding and XAML are declarative, setting values and giving instructions via C# is imperative. Imperative is a lot more error prone in my opinion, your second question seemed to ask whether to add the items or animations manually and i would not recommend that.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want multiple objects on your canvas. To do so you need to template an ItemsControl. Template the panel to be a canvas. This is all done in the presentation layer with XAML. Then bind your ItemsControl's ItemsSource to the collection in your view model.