# Generate array of WPF elements from XAML templates

Tags: wpf, controltemplates

I have a WPF program in which must draw an array of "bricks" onto a `Canvas`.  There is a handful of different brick types, each of which  looks different.

I want each brick type to be drawn using a fairly arbitrary fragment of XAML, e.g.

```
<Canvas> <!-- or some other per-brick container -->
    <Rectangle Fill="Brown" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="0.1" Canvas.Left="-1" Canvas.Top="-1" Width="2" Height="2" />
    <Ellipse Fill="Blue" Canvas.Left="-0.8" Canvas.Top="-0.8" Width="1.6" Height="1.6"/>
</Canvas>
```

But I want the code-behind to clone this fragment many times, translating and rotating each copy into position.

This is similar to what an `ItemsControl` does, except I need to calculate my own brick positions.   It also seems similar to what `ControlTemplate`  does, but I don't understand that well enough to solve my problem.

Can anyone explain how it should be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches but the one I'd go for is using view models and yes, an ItemsControl. You can specify what type of container the ItemsControl should use and pass a Canvas in, and then you can bind a collection of Bricks to the ItemsSource of the ItemsControl.

Then for each type of brick you can define a DataTemplate that specifies how that type should be rendered. If the items have properties such as X and Y you can bind those to the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Right properties in the DataTemplate and off you go...

A good example of what I mean is https://stackoverflow.com/a/1030191/430661 (the most upvoted answer, not the selected one), except there the item template is specified inline instead of through DataTemplates. Just leave the itemTemplate empty and let the framework select the proper DataTemplate based on type.

Now on the other hand if you expect to have many bricks on screen, or perform complex animations on them, or anything like that... this probably won't perform well enough for that kind of scenarios. But then you're probably better off not using WPF for that anyway...

Let me know if you need more help and I can throw together a sample for you.

Comment: This looks like right approach (typical brick count is about 20-100).  The thing I didn't know was that I could pass a `Canvas` into an `ItemsControl`.   The sample @qntmfred's answer to the other question shows how to do this, right?  I expect I will accept your answer once I have it working.

Comment: Yup, you just specify the ItemsPanel of the ItemsControl to be a Canvas inside an ItemsPanelTemplate.

Comment: It's working so far.  But I don't understand how to use multiple Datatemplates and then select the right one. (Worst comes to worst I can get away with multiple ItemsControls, but that's brutal).

Comment: Well the simplest way is to have multiple types (perhaps all derived from a base one), and have one DataTemplate per type: <DataTemplate DataType={x:Type bricks:WoodenBrick}>... etc. Alternatively you can use a DataTemplateSelector to return the correct DataTemplate - it's  a tiny bit messier but completely doable.