# ListBox on Canvas: overlay multiple canvases or use CompositeCollection?

Tags: wpf, canvas, compositecollection

In wpf with mvvm I use a ListBox with Canvas as ItemsPanelTemplate and DataTemplates to customize appearance.
I would like to improve performance by first adding all items of type 1 to the drawing, then all items of type 2.
I could create two ListBoxes both with Canvas as ItemsPanelTemplate and they would be overlays.
Panning and scrolling could be synchronized by means of bindings.
This way I can raise PropertyChanges for both lists independantly from each other.

Question: do you have experience whether overlaying canvases is good or bad for performance?

I an not sure whether this is also possible using a CompositeCollection for the ItemsSource of one ListBox. Or for that matter give both types a common subclass and stay with ObservableCollection.

Question: do you think that somehow a list with CompositeCollection can be given separate PropertyChanges for different parts of the Collection?

EDIT:
Suppose I have a great number of points, lines, labels for the canvas, each of a different type, however with a common base type. I select the DataTemplate using DataType: `DataType="{x:Type my:Point}"`, `DataType="{x:Type my:Line}"` etc.
First as quicly as possible I want the user to see the lines. I raise `PropertyChanged("Lines")` and the ListBox+Canvas for the lines is visible.
In a backgroundworker I raise `PropertyChanged("Points")` and the ListBox2+Canvas2 for the points is visible.
When done in another backgroundworker I raise `PropertyChanged("Labels")` and the ListBox3+Canvas3 for the labels is visible.

Comment: Why are you bothering with ListBox in the first place?  Why not just use 2 `Canvas` types directly, and bind their children?

Comment: ListBox has it's Selection behaviour to offer on top of what ItemsControl has. Binding to Canvas children directly is not possible (http://stackoverflow.com/q/889825/138078) is it?

Comment: But you can use the ItemsControl directly - and if you're stacking them, the selection behavior won't/shouldn't matter

Comment: I have the same question for ItemsControl. Would it be possible to give its ItemsSource two independent updates?

Comment: Nope - there's only one ItemsSource - so you either need to concat the items in the bound value, or use 2 controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a much simpler solution using basic Object Oriented Programming. Create a base data type and make all of your data objects extend from it. It could be empty, but if nothing else, you *could* implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in it so you don't have to in  each of the other data types.

Then you simply add a property of type `ObservableCollection<BaseClass>` to your view model or code behind and data bind *that* to the `ListBox.ItemsSource` property. As long as you *don't* set the `x:Key` values on the different `DataTemplate`s, then WPF will implicitly set them to the relevant data type objects when it renders them.

So you can put *all* of your different data types in the same collection. Then you can add your first type in and wait for however long and add some of a different type, or whatever order you feel like.

---

UPDATE >>>

In response to the edit in your question, I don't quite understand the reason for you trying to use the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to show the items, type by type. If you have the base class collection that I mentioned above, then you simply add the instances of the first type to the collection first, so they'll appear first. When you want the next type to appear, just add them into the collection and then they'll appear and so on. The `ObservableCollection` will take care of that.

Comment: I also considered this. Just I also considered somehow to be able to give a `PropertChanged("Points")`, `PropertChanged("Lines")`, `PropertChanged("Labels") instead of `PropertChanged("All")`.

Comment: B.t.w. "WPF will implicitly set them to the relevant data type objects": an example of what you mean exactly?

Comment: And I also was just curious about the idea of overlaying canvases. That doesn't look bad to me. It's like layers in common drawing applications.

Comment: Please explain further what you mean by these `PropertyChanged` messages (maybe at the end of your question). If you *explicity* declare a value for the `DataTemplate` like this: `<DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate">`, then you'll have to *explicity* set it to an `ItemTemplate` or similar property to apply it. If you *don't* set the `x:Key` value, then WPF will *implicitly*, or automatically, apply it for you (when it finds an object of the type declared in the `DataTemplate`.

Comment: You are probably right, my idea doesn't really add anything.